# XSL transformation new line delimiter &#xA; problem in Strings with &#xA;

Tags: xml, string, xslt, delimiter

I have problem with converting to CSV. Exactly with $RowDelim in the XSL transformation. As you can see below Row delimiter is `&#xA;`. Everything is good till moment that in the table in some string row suddenly enter appeared, than it's is reacting as new row but it's wrong behaviour for me. Do you know appropriate method for this ? I tried a lot of different sometimes maybe wrong this but it's not working

Current Tree of XML:

```
<Rowsets>
<Rowset>
    <Columns>
        <Column Description="id" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="id" SQLDataType="-5" SourceColumn="id"/>
        <Column Description="Note" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Note" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Note"/>
    </Columns>
    <Row>
    <id>9</id>
    <Note>Normal string without enter in string look like this</Note>
    </Row>
    <Row>
    <id>9</id>
    <Note>
    String with enter look like this
    </Note>
    </Row>
</Rowset>
```

I know that i need to change exactly this part:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Row">
```

rest of the code

```
<xsl:value-of select="$RowDelim"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Below complete XSL transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java">
<xsl:output method="text" media-type="text/csv" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:param name="RowDelim">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="FieldDelim">,</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="StringDelim">"</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="DateFormat">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Rowsets">
        <xsl:call-template name="PrintFatalError"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Rowset">
            <xsl:variable name="CurrentColumns" select="Columns"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Columns">
                <xsl:for-each select="Column">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$StringDelim"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$StringDelim"/>
                    <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$FieldDelim"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:value-of select="$RowDelim"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:variable name="ColName">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="ColType">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$CurrentColumns/Column[@Name=$ColName]/@SQLDataType"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$ColType= '2' or $ColType= '3' or $ColType= '4' or $ColType= '5' or $ColType= '6' or $ColType= '7' or $ColType= '8' or $ColType= '-7' or $ColType ='-5' or $ColType ='-3' or $ColType ='-4' or $ColType ='-2'">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test=". = 'NA'">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$StringDelim"/>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$ColType= '91' or $ColType= '92' or $ColType= '93'">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test=". = 'TimeUnavailable'">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="java:com.sap.xmii.Illuminator.ext.ExtFunctions.dateFromXMLFormat(string(.),$DateFormat)"/>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$StringDelim"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$FieldDelim"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:value-of select="$RowDelim"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="PrintFatalError">
    <xsl:for-each select="FatalError">
        <xsl:text>Fatal Error - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$RowDelim"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: use `normalize-space()` function. As in `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>`

Comment: Thank you i didn't use xslt before. It's works.